# Resetting input properties in PHP class

Tags: php, class, properties

Developing further the class first referred to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632599/accessing-array-element-within-public-function-in-a-php-class/46633827#46633827).

My aim is to create a class where $inputNumber and $inputArray can be reset, but the methods below don't seem to work.

```
class myClass
{
public $inputNumber = 27;
public $inputArray = array(1, 2, 4);
public $outputArray = array();

public function setInput($newNumber)
{
    $this->inputNumber = $newNumber;
}

public function setArray($newArray)
{
    $this->inputArray = $newArray;
}

function __construct() {
   $this->outputArray= array($this->inputArray[0]*$this->inputNumber, 
                             $this->inputArray[1]*$this->inputNumber, 
                             $this->inputArray[2]*$this->inputNumber
                             );
}

public function printOutput()
{
    $output = "1st value is " . $this->outputArray[0] . "<br>";
    $output .= "2nd value is " . $this->outputArray[1] . "<br>";
    $output .= "3rd value is " . $this->outputArray[2] . "<br>";
    return $output;
}

}

$obj = new myClass;
$obj = setInput(54);
$obj = setArray(array(6, 12, 24);
echo $obj->printOutput();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `outputArray` is calculated in the construction of the class, which happens before you've set your input and array.

You should move the calculation logic to its own method, e.g.:

```
public function calculateOutput()
{
    $this->outputArray= array(
        $this->inputArray[0] * $this->inputNumber, 
        $this->inputArray[1] * $this->inputNumber, 
        $this->inputArray[2] * $this->inputNumber
    );
}

public function printOutput()
{
    // Calculate your result now
    $this->calculateOutput();

    $output = "1st value is " . $this->outputArray[0] . "<br>";
    $output .= "2nd value is " . $this->outputArray[1] . "<br>";
    $output .= "3rd value is " . $this->outputArray[2] . "<br>";
    return $output;
}
```

Then remove the constructor and your code should work as you have it already.